# getting error using delete sysmails using below query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want this is auto proccess so that I am using getdate()-4 so please help me.

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_delete_log_sp  
    @logged_before = GETDATE()-4 ;  
GO
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187926.aspx)

> You cannot specify a function name as a parameter default value or as
>   the value passed to a parameter when executing a procedure

Try this way

```
DECLARE @tdy_date DATETIME = Getdate() - 4

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.Sysmail_delete_log_sp
  @logged_before = @tdy_date
```

Comment: **prdp** Done thanks. @prdp